# What would be an r equivalent of goto statements (from e.g. c++) here?

Tags: r, loops, label, goto

I realised that r does not have goto statements, and I'm currently translating some C++ code that had them. In the follow code the goto loop is supposed to make the function go back to "loop:" and start running the code from there. How could you achieve a similar result in r?

```
Solve <- function() 
{
  statements
  loop:
    iter_time <- iter_time + 1
  if (conditions) {
    statements
  } else if (conditions) {
    statements
    if(conditions) {
      statements
      if (conditions) {
        statements
      } else {
        statements
      }
    } else {
      goto loop
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `next` to go back to the start of the loop. For example:

```
for (i in 1:5) {
        if (i == 2) {
                print(paste0(i, " is a cool number!"))
        }
        else if (i == 3) {
                print(paste0(i, " is an awesome number!"))
        }
        else {
                next
        }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to make the for loop go indefinitely?

Comment: What I mean is that if the first if statement is true, then it does not loop through the for loop again, but if it is false it goes to the else statement which says do it again (next).

Comment: @VictorNielsen do you want your loop to stop completely as soon as the first `if` condition is met?

Comment: Yes, I want it to move on if the if condition is met and start over if it is not.

Comment: You can use `break` if you want the loop to stop at a certain point.

Comment: I'll try and play around a bit with it, thank you!